# Set observable/computed value from a foreach of inputs knockoutjs

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

It's my first time working with KnockoutJS, and I have a little bit of problem.
I'm trying to get multiple values from inputs then set the addition of the values to a observable or make a computed that get the result of the addition. But I can't figure out how, because the table it's generated from a database and I don't know the quantity of rows until I run the app. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Here is a capture of the site 
[image: Site capture]

I need in the field "INVERSION TOTAL DEL MES" the adition of the values from the inputs from "IMPORTE TOTAL"

Here's the part of the html with the bindings

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: RendicionesPager.pagedRows"> 
                                <tr><td class="text-right">$  <input style="width:90%;text-align:right" data-bind="textInput:ImporteTotal" /></td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="7" class="text-right" >INVERSION TOTAL DEL MES</td>
                            <td class="text-right"><span data-bind="text:'$ ' + InversionDelMes()"></span></td>
                        </tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do something like:

```
 InversionDelMes = ko.computed(function(){
      return  RendicionesPager.pagedRows.reduce(function(p,n){ return p.ImporteTotal + n.ImporteTotal ;});
    });
```

You will need to adjust all contexts, add () if ImporteTotal is an observable etc.etc but you get the idea :)

**Edit:** to explain better, create a ko computed, that will be updated when RendicionesPager.pagedRows is changed, and each time it will aggregate the ImporteTotal field of all contained elements and return it.

Also have in mind that this will work when you add/remove items from your observable array RendicionesPager.pagedRows (if it is obsArray that is). If you want to recalculate your values as a total each time a user changes an input value then you would have to subscribe to each observable field and run a similar logic,for example

```
ImporteTotal.subscribe(function(){ 
    myTotal = RendicionesPager.pagedRows.reduce(function(p,n){
         return p.ImporteTotal + n.ImporteTotal ;
         });
    });
```

so that when any of the observables changes its value, it will fun this function which will in turn update the total value

Comment: It doesn't work for me, if I set importeTotal = ko.observable(123) then that value is setted to InversionDelMes, but in the input when it loadead appaers 0, and when I changed the value it doesn't trigger the function, I understand the approach and it should work but it doesn't

Comment: could you create a simple fiddle for this case and link me here? i can get onto it as soon as i get home,otherwise ill make something for you

Comment: *when i get home, that is :P

Comment: No problem, there's no rush,  i just went back from work, and i can't bring the code with me. So i'll go back to this tomorrow. as soon as i enter the office i'll make the fiddle, because it's a little messy without it. I really apreciatte your help